# Unable to launch chrome - Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Release:    14.04

Codename:   trusty

Google Chrome 48.0.2564.82

When launching Chrome on a fresh installation, it crashes. We get this error (when launched from the command line):

```
$ google-chrome [7251:7251:0123/174646:ERROR:logging.h(808)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects: object_path= /: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetManagedObjects" with signature "" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" doesn't exist [7251:7251:0123/174647:ERROR:logging.h(808)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects: object_path= /: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetManagedObjects" with signature "" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" doesn't exist Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to troubleshoot this? Any further data I can provide that would help?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Web Browser from the chrome website.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64.

Remove it all and restart, for one.
Next have you downloaded the file from the main page?

If so make sure you download the right version.
My file name is google-chrome-stable-current-amd64.deb

https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/ <---That's where I got it from.

Before you download the file check on the power button, about your system...Don't download x64 if you don't have that...Never had an issue with x32 on windows but I would still install the same as your OS...That might be the issue or you've installed it the wrong way!!!

If you got the file double click it and wait for the Ubuntu software center to install it for you.

Good Luck & I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This was performed. No effect (same error).

Comment: Sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

If you had Adobe font 'source-han-serif' on your Ubuntu, try to remove it and

**$ fc-cache -f -v**

then you can launch Chrome succeeded.

### Below messages were what I had when Chrome unable to launch from **strace** command.

> stat("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/source-han-serif/Bold/OTC", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
>
> stat("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/source-han-serif/Bold/cidfont.ps.CN", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=18850096, ...}) = 0
>
> openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/source-han-serif/Bold/cidfont.ps.CN", O_RDONLY) = 31
>
> fcntl(31, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
>
> fstat(31, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=18850096, ...}) = 0
> mmap(NULL, 18850096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 31, 0) = 0x7f062d117000
>
> close(31)                               = 0
> --- SIGILL {si_signo=SIGILL, si_code=ILL_ILLOPN, si_addr=0x55d2d7d7034c} ---
>
> +++ killed by SIGILL (core dumped) +++
>
> Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a determined package is not supported by our system, but we would like to install it anyways:

1. Try to uninstall chrome first.
2. Then open the terminal and type:

`sudo snap install chromium`

or

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

And, at least try with Ubuntu's Software Center.

> Assuming you're using the last Ubuntu version because it's not allowed here to ask UbuntuAsk related to outdated Ubuntu versions.

> This will install Chromium

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issues. If you have your chrome synced with the cloud, try making a backup of `~/.config/google-chrome/` directory and then removing it.

#### How my problem began:

I opened crashsafari **(DISCLAIMER: DO NOT OPEN THAT SITE)** ignorantly. My computer got hanged due to excessive memory requests. I have 16GB RAM and 18GB swap with 2x2TB HDDs. I just waited, and killed all the chrome processes. Turned off swap, and turned it on again (to speed up my programs). Since killing chrome, I was not able to use it properly. It would crash within 5 seconds of starting.

#### What I tried:

1. Reinstalling chrome multiple times.
2. Editing the `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences` file and changed all `"state":1` to `"state":0`.
3. Forcibly disabling extensions/plugins at startup with verbose logging using the following command line: 
   `google-chrome-stable --disable-extensions --disable-plugins --enable-logging=stderr --v=1`

Everytime, I would get some error like this (not posting complete log):

```
[14408:14434:0130/030351:FATAL:memory_linux.cc(43)] Out of memory.
```

#### What I finally did:

Concluded that the problem was due to some corrupted file in `~/.config/google-chrome`. Made a backup of that directory and removed it. Now my chrome works like a charm. Relogged-in for sync to work. Bookmarks, history, passwords, extensions etc. were all synced perfectly. I lost logged-in sessions but that's no big deal for me :D

Hope that helped someone. Good luck.