# How do I start chromium-browser in headless mode? extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99"

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, headless, randr

## Ubuntu

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

## Chromium

```
chromium-browser --version
Chromium 48.0.2564.116 Ubuntu 14.04
```

I am serving a Flask web application on `localhost` and I want to browse to it in headless mode.

Following this [lead on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210765/any-way-to-start-google-chrome-in-headless-mode)

## Prerequisite

```
$ apt-get install xvfb imagemagick
```

#### X virtual frame buffer `xvfb-run`

Running **Chromium** with the following options

```
--allow-running-insecure-content    // trying to get passed
--ignore-certificate-errors         // the self-signed certs
--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests   //
--disable-gpu                       
--no-sandbox
```

the command

```
 xvfb-run --server-args='-screen 0, 1024x768x24' chromium-browser --allow-running-insecure-content --ignore-certificate-errors --ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests  --disable-gpu --no-sandbox https://admin:password@localhost
```

## Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".

```
[2596:2596:0407/170544:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(206)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
[2596:2596:0407/170544:ERROR:desktop_window_tree_host_x11.cc(892)] Not implemented reached in virtual void views::DesktopWindowTreeHostX11::InitModalType(ui::ModalType)
[2596:2596:0407/170545:ERROR:logging.h(808)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects: object_path= /: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetManagedObjects" with signature "" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" doesn't exist
[2596:2596:0407/170545:ERROR:logging.h(808)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects: object_path= /: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetManagedObjects" with signature "" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" doesn't exist
[2596:2596:0407/170629:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_x11.cc(62)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
```

### Without `--disable-gpu` and `--no-sandbox`

```
[3122:3122:0407/172728:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(338)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process
[3062:3099:0407/172728:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(144)] Failed to create channel.
```

## UPDATE 20160407

```
$ sudo Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -ac +extension GLX +extension RANDR +render -noreset &
$ export DISPLAY=":1"
$ chromium-browser --allow-running-insecure-content --ignore-certificate-errors --ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests  --disable-gpu --no-sandbox https://admin:password@localhost
```

getting

```
[3413:3413:0407/174058:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(206)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
[3413:3413:0407/174058:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(256)] Gtk: cannot open display: :1
[3422:3422:0100/000000:ERROR:zygote_linux.cc(674)] write: Broken pipe
```

Also tried with `google-chrome`

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Version

```
google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 49.0.2623.110
```

and I am getting the same errors including `extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".`

## Related posts

[any-way-to-start-google-chrome-in-headless-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210765/any-way-to-start-google-chrome-in-headless-mode)

[how-to-add-the-missing-randr-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644001/how-to-add-the-missing-randr-extension)

[unable-to-launch-chrome-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724830/unable-to-launch-chrome-ubuntu)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did something similar on a non-Ubuntu Linux distro. For testing purposes I will use my HTPC running Ubuntu (14.04) to make sure it works there as well with minimal changes.

## Distro Information

```
htpc@HTPC:[~]:$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

### Making sure the display we want to use isn't present yet

```
htpc@HTPC:[~]:$ DISPLAY=:1 xset q
xset:  unable to open display ":1"
```

### Starting Xvfb

Sudo is not needed. I run it as the same user who also starts the browser.

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 '1280x1024x16' -ac &> /dev/null &
```

### Make sure the display is present and owned by yourself

```
htpc@HTPC:[~]:$ ls -l /tmp/.X11-unix/X1
srwxrwxrwx 1 htpc htpc 0 Apr 15 11:37 /tmp/.X11-unix/X1
```

### Export current display to the **:1** we just created.

We can also add **DISPLAY=:1** before every command we want to run on the display. However exporting makes sure this will be saved for the current session so you don't have to provide it for every command.

```
export DISPLAY=:1
```

### Another check to make sure the screen is present and is working (and also that the export bit is working)

```
htpc@HTPC:[~]:$ xset q
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  660    repeat rate:  25
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  600    cycle:  600
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x20    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Display is not capable of DPMS
```

### Extra debugging step

I will be running **nc** which will print verbosely if Chrome is trying to contact it. So we'll know whether this setup works. Another way is to run a **VNC** server on the same display and connect to it so you can see what the browser is doing and whether is **Chrome** is starting up properly. Which I would recommend! **Chrome** might be giving different errors in the UI which cannot be seen in the console in your case.

```
htpc@HTPC:[~]:$ echo Testing... | nc -l 9999 -v &
[2] 8416
htpc@HTPC:[~]:$ Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 9999)
```

### Time to start **Chrome**!

```
htpc@HTPC:[~]:$ google-chrome --disable-gpu 'http://localhost:9999' &
[3] 8512
htpc@HTPC:[~]:$ [8512:8512:0415/115726:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(271)] Gtk: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1".
Connection from [127.0.0.1] port 9999 [tcp/*] accepted (family 2, sport 40050)
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9999
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

As you can see above the **RANDR** error it still present, just ignore it. Below it you see the HTTP request done by **Chrome** (see User-Agent bit) to the **nc** process we started. Seems **Chrome** is starting up as expected and visiting the URL provided.

### Trying the same with Chromium

```
htpc@HTPC:[~]:$ chromium-browser --disable-gpu 'http://localhost:9999' &
[3] 13108
htpc@HTPC:[~]:$ Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1".
[13108:13108:0415/145854:ERROR:logging.h(813)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects: object_path= /: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetManagedObjects" with signature "" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" doesn't exist

Connection from [127.0.0.1] port 9999 [tcp/*] accepted (family 2, sport 40542)
[13108:13108:0415/145854:ERROR:logging.h(813)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects: object_path= /: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetManagedObjects" with signature "" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" doesn't exist

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9999
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/49.0.2623.108 Chrome/49.0.2623.108 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Doing the same has pretty much the same effect, with some other additional warnings. The User-Agent is Chromium as expected.

## Extra

If you want to keep it all running do not forget to issue the **disown** command per process and keep them running in the background to make sure that they are not killed when you logout. See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-disown-command-examples-usage-syntax/ for more info about **disown**.

Comment: Do you mind running `chromium-browser` and post the output? thanks for the detailed answer. Real neat!

Comment: I added a block with chromium as requested. See post for details.

Comment: Doesn't seem so. I'd recommend using VNC server so you can see what is actually happening inside the virtual screen. Let me know if you cannot get VNC to work.

Comment: I have set up VNC server, `vncserver` is on `:2`, how do you start it on the virtual framebuffer. I have tried `vncserver :1` but the VNC client doesn't seem to be able to connect

Comment: it doesn't let me start `vncserver` on display `:1` ...`A VNC server is already running as :1` ... but I don't have another `vncserver` running ... puzzles me

Comment: Doesn't look like I can start `Xvfb` and `vncserver` on the same display ... I tried starting VNC server first `vncserver :1` and then `Xvfb :1` ... and the other way around. I was able to make it work

Comment: I may have figured it out using `x11vnc -display :1 -localhost ` (instead of `vncserver`) and connect the VNC client to `localhost:0`

Comment: Yeah that will work. `x11vnc` allows you to host any display already running in X over the VNC protocol, whilst `vncserver` automatically starts a virtual display. So just running `vncserver` is enough to start an empty display. In my case it starts one at `:2` as `:1` is already in use. Simply exporting `DISPLAY`as before to `:2` and starting `chromium-browser` should work for `vncserver`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38439/discussion-between-joel-and-serrie).