# chrome not opeing

Tags: google-chrome, 19.04

When I click Chrome icon it doesn't open. When I run `google-chrome` on terminal I got this error.

[image: error image]

I've tried the solutions below, but nothing seems to work for me.

1. [Illegal instruction (core dumped) / chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158807/)
2. [Unable to launch chrome - Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724830/)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Askubuntu. Please don't use a screenshot of the terminal. Please edit your question: copy and paste your error into the question and then select/highlight the pasted code and then press CTRL+K to format the text as code. This helps us check the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```bsh
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And then:

```bsh
sudo apt install --reinstall google-chrome-stable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```bsh
sudo apt install --reinstall google-chrome-stable
```

Or try to get the .deb file from [Chrome.com](https://chrome.com/download).